# Laravel Ratchet not reading config file after vendor:publish

Tags: php, laravel, ratchet

Im trying to make Socket server base on [laravel-ratchet](https://github.com/Askedio/laravel-ratchet).

ive done installation steps from git  :

```
1."composer require askedio/laravel-ratchet"

2. "$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Askedio\LaravelRatchet\Providers\LaravelRatchetServiceProvider"
```

then ive entered class address in **app.php** like this :

```
Askedio\LaravelRatchet\Providers\LaravelRatchetServiceProvider::class,
```

now from this [help](https://packagist.org/packages/hansen1416/laravel-ratchet) ive created my simple socket **IoServer** class in app folder (**App/MyRatchetSocketServer**):

```
<?php

namespace App;


use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Askedio\LaravelRatchet\RatchetServer;

class MyRatchetSocketServer extends RatchetServer
{
    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $conn, $input)
    {
        parent::onMessage($conn, $input);

        if (!$this->throttled) {
            $this->send($conn, 'Hello you.');

            $this->sendAll('Hello everyone.');

            $this->send($conn, 'Wait, I don\'t know you! Bye bye!');

            $this->abort($conn);
        }
    }
}
```

then ive changed my **/config/ratchet.php** to this :

```
<?php

return [
    'class'           => \App\MyRatchetSocketServer::class,
    'host'            => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'            => '8989',
    'connectionLimit' => false,
    'throttle'        => [
        'onOpen'    => '5:1',
        'onMessage' => '20:1',
     ],
    'abortOnMessageThrottle' => false,
    'blackList'              => [],
    'zmq'                    => [
        'host'   => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'   => 5555,
        'method' => \ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL,
    ],
];
```

and in final part im going to start my service with serve :

```
php artisan ratchet:serve
```

and it gives this error :

```
Starting WampServer server on: 0.0.0.0:8080

In RatchetServerCommand.php line 204:

  Askedio\LaravelRatchet\Examples\Pusher must be an instance of Askedio\LaravelRatchet\RatchetWampServer to create a Wamp server
```

my guess is that , serve command is bypassing the ratchet config file.

also if i try this :

```
php artisan ratchet:serve --driver=IoServer --class="App\MyRachetSocketServer::class"
```

the error changed to this :

```
Starting IoServer server on: 0.0.0.0:8080

In RatchetServerCommand.php line 155:

  Class 'App\MyRachetSocketServer::class' not found
```

the file path is correct (bottom pic). dont know what to test next ?!

[image]

Im using Xamp , Vscode , Laravel 5.5.

Comment: Maybe try adding a backwards slash to php artisan ratchet:serve --driver=IoServer --class="\App\MyRachetSocketServer::class"

Comment: @Polaris done that , and still no result ;(

Comment: Maybe try putting the class name in quotes, since it is an array and it should be a string? return [
    'class'           => \App\MyRatchetSocketServer::class,

Comment: @Polaris thanks for help after clearing cache from suggested answer , it detects the class normaly , cheer XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem long time ago

after a few try , find out that it was a cache problem.

try this [Package](https://github.com/afrazahmmad/clear-all-cached-data)  for clearing cache with this command :

```
php artisan clear:data
```

or u can use these generic command in order:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:cache
```

and finaly , try your server command as follows :

```
php artisan ratchet:serve --driver=IoServer
```

hope that helps :)